# Operator in $L^2$ Space

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have to calculate Ker, Im and norm of the operator, defined in $L^2(-\pi, \pi):
$
$[Tf] (x) =cos(x) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{ af(y)\over a^2+y^2}dy $, where $a>0.$

My problem is how to analyze Ker.
I can for sure say that every odd function belongs $Ker [TF](x)$ but I don't know if it exists some even fuction which belongs to it.Maybe  I should calculate Fourier Series of $g(x) = {1\over a^2+x^2}$ but I don't know how to solve integrals like $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} {cos(nx) \over x^2+a^2} dx$. I thought to use residue theorem but I don't know how to do it because I have both trigonometric and polynomial functions . I also tried to put this integral on wolfram alpha calculator but it can't calculate it. Thanks in advance to everyone will help me. P.S. sorry for my bad English, I'm Italian.

Comment: Depends what kind of description you want to have. You could just say that $Ker(T)$ is the orthogonal complement of $(a^2+x^2)^{-1}$.